Upgrade from Angular 7 to 14 - routing problem -redirectTo and canActivate cannot be used together
I get this error Error: NG04014: redirectTo and canActivate cannot be used together. Redirects happen before activation so canActivate will never be executed. after upgrading angular 7 to 14. Anyone can help ?
i have tried to remove that Gaurd but still facing the issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

export const RUN_PAGES: Routes = [
{
path: 'risks',
redirectTo: 'review',
pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
path: 'models',
canActivate: [RedirectGuard],
component: RedirectGuard,
data: {
showRunNavigation: false,
menuIconClass: 'icon-test-tube',
menuText: 'Models',
customTitle: true,
customNavigation: true
}
},

You can move the redirect into the guard and use the router to redirect
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class RedirectGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private readonly router: Router) {}

canActivate() {
    this.router.navigate(['redirect']);
    return false;
  }
}

I've provided a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7rkegm?file=src%2Fapp%2Frouting.module.ts
